# how to understand pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python-3.x, py-telegram-bot-api

I 'am a new to programing, and I like python, I study python by my self and with lots of searching on the internet created my first Telegram bot.

But I want to understand one thing, how the hell I can understand the documentation of the API of pyTelegramBotAPI and Telegram API, for example on telegram page we can find this text that explain about messages:"
sendMessage
Use this method to send text messages. On success, the sent Message is returned.
"

But there is no place where you can understand how the hell you suppose to use it !

If some one can please guide me about that it will be really appreciated since I straggle to
understand what is the write way to understand that and how to use the methods or any other thing.

Thank you very much for your help !